# How to pass time function data in clickhouse

Tags: mysql, clickhouse

I have mysql table which consists of fields `(from_time, to_time)` having `time` data type. Here is below my table description and some data from that table.

[image]

[image]

I want to migrate mysql data to clickhouse. Clickhouse accepts the `time` data type field as a `string`. But when I try to dump data from mysql to clickhouse it shows me the following error.

```
CRITICAL:ex='datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Is there any solution ??

Comment: it looks that this bug related to mysql - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52469341/django-attribute-error-datetime-timedelta-object-has-no-attribute-decode.

Comment: to connect to mysql table from CH can be used [mysql table function](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/table-functions/mysql/#mysql). To dump data just do *insert into ch_table select * from mysql_table_func*.